# Undesired spaces with tikzpicture inside a dynamically built tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, spacing, loops

I'm trying to build a dynamic table in witch each cell contains a tikzpicture without any addictional margin around it.

The entire structure is pretty complex, so i made an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{Row}
\newcounter{Col}

\newcommand{\Foo}{%
    \par\raggedright\centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \forLoop{1}{3}{Row}
        {
            \forLoop{1}{4}{Col}
            {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[black] (0,0) rectangle (1, -1);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\theCol}{4}}{\\ \hline}{&}
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
}%

\begin{document}

    \Foo

\end{document}
```

The result of this code have undesired margins on the left of each tikzpicture.

[image: The resulting table]

I tried to make the same code without for loops and margins doesn't appear.

[image]

Can someone help me find the problem inside my code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please extend your code snipped to complete small document starting with `\documentclass{...} and ending with `end{document}`. Help us to help you!

Comment: You put rectangles (with a border) into tabular cells which have also a border (since you use `|` and `\hline`.

Comment: If I try to remove tabular lines the output is the same.. but If I try to do the same manually without for loops margins disappear... so I think that the problem is inside looping commands :/ Can't understand what have I to do to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried `draw=none`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spurious spaces!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{Row}
\newcounter{Col}

\newcommand{\Foo}{%
    \par\raggedright\centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \forLoop{1}{3}{Row}
        {% <--- HERE
            \forLoop{1}{4}{Col}
            {% <--- HERE
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[black] (0,0) rectangle (1, -1);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\theCol}{4}}{\\ \hline}{&}
            }% <--- not so important
        }% <--- not so important
    \end{tabular}% <--- not so important
}

\begin{document}

    \Foo

\end{document}
```

The two end-of-lines marked as `HERE` are the responsible for the unwanted spaces. I added some more `%` characters for uniformity.

Answer (score 0):

I've just replaced your table head with just `c` and some (just tested) negative hspace and this is the result:

[image: picture]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{Row}
\newcounter{Col}

\newcommand{\Foo}{%
    \par\raggedright\centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip -3.5pt}c@{\hskip -3.5pt}c@{\hskip -3.5pt}c}
        \forLoop{1}{3}{Row}
        {
            \forLoop{1}{4}{Col}
            {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (1, -1);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\theCol}{4}}{\\}{&}
            }
        }
    \end{tabular}
}%

\begin{document}

    \Foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's clear that the problem isn't disappear... the addictional margin is still inside every cell. Also, I need to draw the rectangle because I need to use tikzpicture to draw a more complex image in my original project.

Comment: @Zanomate I've changed my approach and now it bases on the `tikzpicture` margins.